# Color a whole row in rhandsontable based on a string value in one column

Tags: r, rhandsontable

I have an rhandsontable and I want the WHOLE ROW to be yellow if the cell in the text in the last column ("Comments") includes string "missed".

The code below highlights any cell that has a value 'missed', but not the whole row. Besides, I'd like the row to turn yellow when a cell in the last column CONTAINS "missed" - even inside a longer string, and not just when it contains only "missed" - as it is written now - I just don't know how to match strings in JavaScript.

```
DF = data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, Comments = c("missed etc", "missed"))
rhandsontable(DF, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = " function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) { 
                     Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments); 
                     if(value == 'missed') { 
                     td.style.background = 'yellow' } 
                     }")
```

Thank you very much!

To clarify, in reality, I am dealing with a larger table that I am rendering in rShiny. So, ideally the solution that works for the little data frame above should also work here. Currently it is not (nothing shows up at all):

```
    output$session_table <- renderRHandsontable({
        req(input$select_a_patient)
        patient_nr <- which(patient_names_reactive$names %in% input$select_a_patient)

        row_highlight = which(grepl("missed", 
sessions_reactive$sessions[[patient_nr]]$Comments))-1

        rhandsontable(sessions_reactive$sessions[[patient_nr]],
                      row_highlight = row_highlight,
                      width = 1000, height = 500) %>% 
            hot_rows(fixedRowsTop = 1) %>%
            hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>% 
            hot_validate_numeric(cols = c(3, 5), min = 0, max = 500) %>% 
            hot_col(c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8), valign = 'htCenter') %>%
            hot_cols(renderer = " 
            function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) { 
                     Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments); 

                     tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]
                     hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
                     hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows]

                     if (hrows.includes(row)) { 
                       td.style.background = 'yellow' } 
                     }") %>% hot_col(c(5, 8), renderer = " 
                        function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                           Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                           td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                           td.style.color = '#fc0f03';}"
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tutorial using a custom renderer:

https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/

you could do the following (doing the string match outside of the js).

```
DF = data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 3:6, Comments = c("missed etc", "", "missed", ""))

rhandsontable(DF, row_highlight = which(grepl("missed", DF$Comments))-1, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) { 
                     Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments); 

                     tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]

                     hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
                     hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows]

                     if (hrows.includes(row)) { 
                       td.style.background = 'yellow' } 
                     }")
```

**Edit**: This apparently requires additional modification if used as a shiny app. As noted in [documentation](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/):

> When using this approach in a shiny app or in a document with more
>   than one widget, the widget search logic will need to be more robust.

If `instance.params` is available, we can try the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(a=1:10, b=3:12, c=c("Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", 5:11), d=3:12, e=1:10, f=1:10, g=1:10, h=2:11, Comments = c("missed etc", rep("", 7), "missed", ""))

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput('table')
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    row_highlight = which(grepl("missed", DF$Comments))-1
    col_highlight = c(5,8)-1
    rhandsontable(DF, row_highlight = row_highlight, col_highlight = col_highlight, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
      hot_rows(fixedRowsTop = 1) %>%
      hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>% 
      hot_validate_numeric(cols = c(3, 5), min = 0, max = 500) %>% 
      hot_col(c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8), valign = 'htCenter') %>%
      hot_cols(renderer = "
            function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                     Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

                     if (instance.params) {
                       hrows = instance.params.row_highlight
                       hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows]
                       hcols = instance.params.col_highlight
                       hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols]

                       if (hrows.includes(row)) {
                         td.style.background = 'yellow' 
                       }

                       if (hcols.includes(col)) {
                         td.style.fontWeight = 'bold'
                         td.style.color = '#fc0f03'
                       }
                     }
            }"
      ) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit1**: Integrated second renderer with the first one, so that column formatting doesn't overwrite row background color.

**Edit2**: Adding explanation regarding `col_highlight` added.

Starting at the beginning we have `col_highlight = c(5,8)-1` which creates a vector storing the columns we wish to have different formatting (bold, red font). We subtract one since arrays in javascript are zero-based.

The following line for `rhandsontable` allows us to pass in `col_highlight = col_highlight` so that we can later access these selected columns through `instance.params.col_highlight` in the renderer function later on. Once we access them and assign them to `hcols`, we make sure it is an array if it wasn't already.

The statement `if (hcols.includes(col))` checks to see if the `hcols` array contains the column (`col`) being rendered. If the column rendered is 5, this is contained in the vector (5, 8), and the `td.style` would be set to bold and red.

Note that since `hrows` would only change background color, and `hcols` would only change font bold and color, one does not overwrite the other, and can be used together.

[image: table with select yellow background row and red and bold columns]

Comment: Actually, that's really great and answers the question the way I asked it. However, In real life I have some other code that defines different aspects of my table, e.g., "hot_col(c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8), valign = 'htCenter')". Thus, I need to 'continue' my pipe with a "%>%". And I don't know how to do it with your line 'row_highlight <- ...' - because that line is outside of the pipeline... :( Is there any way to achieve the same thing - but inside the rhandsontable function?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben, really appreciate it. Your solution is ingenious - and it totally works with the little data frame.  But it's not working in my larger/longer code. I posted it (along with your solution) at the bottom of my post. Any idea why it's rendering nothing? (clarification: sessions_reactive$sessions[[patient_nr]] is a reactive value - and it is the data frame I am rendering). Can it be that nothing is being shown because currently I don't have 'missed' in the column 'Comments' anywhere?

Comment: No, adding row_highlight = row_highlight inside rhandstontable didn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200098/discussion-between-ben-and-user3245256).

Comment: It's funny - it works perfectly when DT is a standalone table. Again: in my real tables I don't currently have a single comment (in column Comments) with 'missed'. Can this be the reason?

Comment: Ben, I want to thank you very much for all the time you took to solve it. Who would have known it'll end up such a difficult question and that the solution that works in simple rhandsontable is not working inside Shiny. Really appreciate it! PS: notice that the last two elements of the pipe (hot_cols you've written and hot_col after it) overwrite each other (in this case - red font cancels yellow background). That's not a big deal for me, but it would be cool to have them both work on the same cells. It's probably very complicated! :-)

Comment: The whole row highlighting works, but those red columns are not red anymore :) I guess that formatting works in sequence and the last step overwrites the first step.

Comment: You don't get the same result as in my picture? Columns 5 and 8 appear red and bold font? Also did you copy/paste the entire code? It also needs `col_highlight` as well...

Comment: It's working - I missed the parameters (col_highlight on top)! THANK YOU!

Comment: I just realized - I don't understand what the last statement means: if (hcols.includes(col)). I mean, it's working, but I just wanted columns 5 and 8 to be bold and red. I am not sure what hcols.includes(col) means here...

Comment: I added an additional explanation under `Edit2` in the answer above. Hope this is helpful.