# r handsontable: Can a custom renderer negate column formatting commands?

Tags: r, rhandsontable

This rendering of my rhandsontable in Shiny works just fine. Among other things, columns 'Pat. Owes' and 'Ins. Owes' show up formatted as US$ (see lines 4 and 5 from the bottom of the code section below):

```
renderRHandsontable({
      sessions_reactive$sessions[[patient_nr]], 
      row_highlight = row_highlight, col_highlight = col_highlight,
      width = 1000, height = 500) %>% 
      hot_rows(fixedRowsTop = 1) %>%
      hot_col("Pat. Owes", format = "$0,000.00", language = "en-US") %>%
      hot_col("Ins. Owes", format = "$0,000.00", language = "en-US") %>% 
      hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>% 
      hot_validate_numeric(cols = c(3, 5), min = 0, max = 500) %>% 
      hot_col(c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8), valign = 'htCenter')
})
```

The code below - but with those 2 US$-formatting lines commented out - also works fine. The renderer at the bottom does 2 things: makes the font bold and red in columns 5 and 8. And also, the background of the whole row becomes yellow if its last column contains a certain string.

```
    rhandsontable(
      sessions_reactive$sessions[[patient_nr]], 
      row_highlight = row_highlight, col_highlight = col_highlight,
      width = 1000, height = 500) %>% 
      hot_rows(fixedRowsTop = 1) %>%
    # hot_col("Pat. Owes", format = "$0,000.00", language = "en-US") %>%
    # hot_col("Ins. Owes", format = "$0,000.00", language = "en-US") %>% 
      hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>% 
      hot_validate_numeric(cols = c(3, 5), min = 0, max = 500) %>% 
      hot_col(c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8), valign = 'htCenter') %>%
      hot_cols(renderer = "
            function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                     Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

                     if (instance.params) {
                       hrows = instance.params.row_highlight
                       hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows]
                       hcols = instance.params.col_highlight
                       hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols]

                       if (hrows.includes(row)) {
                         td.style.background = 'yellow'
                       }

                       if (hcols.includes(col)) {
                         td.style.fontWeight = 'bold'
                         td.style.color = '#fc0f03'
                       }
                     }
            }")
  })
```

My issue: if I uncomment the 2 commented hot_col lines devoted to US$-formatting - they don't work in combination with my renderer at the bottom. I mean, there is no error, but those 2 columns just do not appear formatted as US$ - they just appear numeric. Clearly, my renderer at the bottom (although it doesn't refer to those columns specifically) somehow negates the US$ formatting.
Moving those 2 lines to the bottom of rhandsontable definition doesn't help either. The render stuff is working, but the US$ formatting isn't.

Any advice? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ben Hi, Ben! :) Really, wasn't the author of rHandsontable telling many people in response to their questions that it should be text renderer?

Comment: Yes, it did! Amazing! Thank you, Ben! Maybe make your comment an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would use `NumericRenderer` instead of `TextRenderer`. My understanding is that `TextRenderer` is the default with no validation. `NumericRenderer` can help with formatting of numbers.

Here's the [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142090/color-a-whole-row-in-rhandsontable-based-on-a-string-value-in-one-column) (with row and column formatting), with the addition of `hot_col` specifying US$ formatting:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(a=1:10, b=3:12, c=c("Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", 5:11), d=3:12, e=1:10, f=1:10, g=1:10, h=2:11, Comments = c("missed etc", rep("", 7), "missed", ""))

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput('table')
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    row_highlight = which(grepl("missed", DF$Comments))-1
    col_highlight = c(5,8)-1
    rhandsontable(DF, row_highlight = row_highlight, col_highlight = col_highlight, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
      hot_rows(fixedRowsTop = 1) %>%
      hot_col(1, format = "$0,000.00", language = "en-US") %>%
      hot_col(2, format = "$0,000.00", language = "en-US") %>% 
      hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>% 
      hot_validate_numeric(cols = c(3, 5), min = 0, max = 500) %>% 
      hot_col(c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8), valign = 'htCenter') %>%
      hot_cols(renderer = "
            function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                     Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

                     if (instance.params) {
                       hrows = instance.params.row_highlight
                       hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows]
                       hcols = instance.params.col_highlight
                       hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols]

                       if (hrows.includes(row)) {
                         td.style.background = 'yellow' 
                       }

                       if (hcols.includes(col)) {
                         td.style.fontWeight = 'bold'
                         td.style.color = '#fc0f03'
                       }
                     }
            }"
      ) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```